# How can I remove this basin waste shim?

Tags: plumbing

Underneath my bathroom basin is this fitment. The bottom screws into a waste trap, and the side opening screws into a plug lever thing.
[image: Waste shim from beneath]

I now want to remove all this to fit a new plug and surround. However I've no idea how to remove it.
[image: Down the shim]

Do the top and bottom halves come apart somehow? I can potentially remove the basin from the pedestal, possibly there is a screw behind the bottom fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, on a pedestal sink (which is what it looks like you have) you will install the drain before setting the bowl in place. If you can't remove the bowl to replace the drain, you will have to figure a way to turn the inside of the drain.  It looks like the stopper lever hole will rotate against the pedestal and stop there, so maybe try jamming a set of pliers inside the bore and rotate.  Frankly, I think you'll be happier just disassembling the bowl.

Comment: Thanks - so there _are_ two parts and they do unscrew from each other?

Comment: @strangerpixel  The idea is they unscrew.  With time and stuff, unscrewing gets more difficult, to sometimes requiring a hacksaw to cut it in pieces from inside the hole.

Comment: @strangerpixel yep, look up some pedestal sink installation videos.  The drain on top may be stuck with crusted plumbers putty, or even silicone.

Comment: Turn the bottom to crack it lose. Then you have to keep it from turning and hitting the pedestal, while you unscrew it from the top... somehow. **Or just don't** install the new drain stuff that comes with the new faucet. Scotch brite pad would clean that right up. If you thew things away, go get them until this is back in working order.

Comment: Thanks - monkey wrench / screwdriver worked in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try a *strainer wrench* to hold/turn the upper strainer ring, whilst also holding the lower portion of the assembly from turning. A bit of spray penetrating oil from below might also help. BTW that type of drain is often called a *pop-up drain assembly*.

[image]

Comment: Having the right tools _always_ makes a job easier!